# Can I use both css and tailwind/bootstrap/others in a react application?

Tags: reactjs

Can I use both css and tailwind/bootstrap/others in a react application?

Answer (score 0):

In a React application, you may utilize CSS as well as Tailwind, Bootstrap, or other CSS frameworks. You may use the CSS framework of your choosing to style your React components by include it in your project. Additionally, if necessary, you may create your own CSS styles for particular components.

Comment: is it good or bad?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine as you please, however it is not recommended. May I ask the reason?
The bundle size of your production build will increase drastically if you use multiple multiple styling libraries